# Spot Rates on Treasuries

Tags: markowitz, spot-rate, treasuries

I am trying to find the spot rates for 1mo, 3mo, and 6mo tbills. This would just be their yields as listed on the treasury website, correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access spot rates on the Treasury website here:

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/economic-policy/corp-bond-yield/Pages/TNC-YC.aspx

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/textview.aspx?data=yield